# How to make google map code below load City, State without LatLong loading first?

Tags: php, javascript

The code below will display the city, state chosen by user from previous page of website. However, map first loads LatLong location, then opens city, state. How can the LatLong variable be eliminated so it does not load? Just want city, state to display.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var marker;

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });

            showAddress('"<?php echo $_SESSION['city_name']; ?>"');
        }

        function showAddress(address) {
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    return;
                }
                if (results.length > 1) {
                    alert('Multiple addresses found; showing first one ...');
                }
                $.each(results, function(i, item) {
                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(item.geometry.location.lat(), item.geometry.location.lng());
                    marker.setPosition(location);
                    map.setCenter(location);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know you could always find the lat-long for the specific city you are looking for and zoom to the right level to fit the area into view. That's how I used it.

Or you could use the geocoder result to send value to latlang
So you will need to call geocoder.geocode() before you initialize the map

Use the line already in your code:

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(item.geometry.location.lat(), item.geometry.location.lng());
```

and then place this after:

```
var latlng = location;
```

Then use the latlng to initialize the map
So you code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var marker;

    function initialize() {

        /*Go through the following to understand what I'm trying to get at.*/
        var address = "<?php echo $_SESSION['city_name']; ?>";
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // This was removed from below. Compare with your code.
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latlang = results[0].geometry.location; } 

            else { alert("The location cannot be mapped"); }
        });

        /* Up until here. */

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });

        showAddress('"<?php echo $_SESSION['city_name']; ?>"');
    }

    function showAddress(address) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                return;
            }
            if (results.length > 1) {
                alert('Multiple addresses found; showing first one ...');
            }
            $.each(results, function(i, item) {
                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(item.geometry.location.lat(), item.geometry.location.lng());
                marker.setPosition(location);
                map.setCenter(location);
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

This should work.

Comment: inserted, "var latlng = location;" after "var location = ...". Getting same result: the map of the latlng coordinates shows first then the city, state opens. Then use latlng to initialize? How to?

Comment: is it clear what i'm trying to do? user selects a city, state from previous page. their selection posts on next page in code above. The location displays on the map. This works except for the fact that the latlng coordinates in the code display briefly, then user selected city appears. just want city to appear only. how to?

Comment: I have updated that answer. Basically I'm calling that geocoder.geocode before you initialize the map. That way I get the coordinates of the city before the map is initialized. Then for the map center property, I use that geocoder info which I have saved to the latlang variable.

Comment: Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: address is not defined" after the geocoder.geocode line. What am i missing? Thanks.

Comment: @jhar From your code :  
`showAddress('"<?php echo $_SESSION['city_name']; ?>"');`
that php line basically sends the address to the **showAddress** function.  
So before the  
`geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)`  
add this:  
`var address = "<?php echo $_SESSION['city_name']; ?>";`

Comment: after inserting var address = "<?php echo $_SESSION['city_name']; ?>"; before the geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) , i got this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'geocode' of undefined" i'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being clumsy : 
Forgot to initialize geocoder.  

`geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

Place that before you call geocoder after 

`var address = "<?php echo $_SESSION['city_name']; ?>"; `

Comment: Also remove the geocoder initialization in here
`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        // THis has to go - geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({`